# Listen to websocket events (written in Javascript) via c#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, websocket

I want to scrape some live data from a site in my application (in C#). This site has authentication (+ captcha which prevents from automating all tasks of web scraping) and uses LightStreamer as websocket client. Now, If i replicate necessary codes of LightStreamer to open and get data via websocket (in javascript language), how can i pass that data from javascript to C#?
I use Selenium chrome driver which gives me ability to login to site and also execute some javascript codes. Am i in right way?
All what i have found up to now, is this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265421/selenium-node-js-is-it-possible-to-listen-for-reoccurring-events) which proposes to inject data to a hidden element and then list to changes in that element via Selenium.

Comment: You can return data right from javascript to the driver.   The executeScript method will return whatever the script you give it returns.

Comment: You're right. But it's done only once. In fact, in javascript executed by driver i'm going to bind some functions to events of websocket. Listening to those events and returning data back to driver  (which is done multiple times) is what i have in my mind. It sounds Selenium can't access websocket events directly, although it can access events of page elements like click directly.